# Reversing Array Without Using Array Size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reverse

It is relatively easy to reverse an array given a pointer to the array and the size of the array.

But my question is: Is it possible to reverse the array given just a pointer to the array?

( in C++ btw)

### EDIT

This was a question apparently asked in an interview at Lockheed Martin. See [here](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Object-Oriented-coding-questions-Given-an-array-you-don-t-know-the-size-make-an-array-that-has-the-elements-in-the-oppo-QTN_208078.htm)

Comment: No, because the answer clearly depends on where the array ends.

Answer (score 2):

In general the answer is **NO**.
It is only possible for so called terminated arrays like NULL-terminated char array:

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
   int end = -1;
   int front = -1;

   while (str[++end] != NULL);  

   while (--end > ++front)
   {   
      char temp = str[end];
      str[end] = str[front];
      str[front] = temp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. If you dont know the size of your array then you cant reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible if you define a "terminator" for your array element type, like \0 used for char arrays. You should always end the array with that value, otherwise you'll obtain runtime errors. But it's always better to use the size or avoid arrays and use vectors since you're using c++ and not c.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Without knowing the size, you cannot use the iterators to reverse it and without using iterators and not knowing the size, it wouldnt be possible to reverse that particular array. You would have to declare another array, copy the contents from the first array into the new array, and perform the content reverse on the new array.